# Using multiple database connection string in web application web ,Doubts about asp.net web application appcode

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection-string, app-code

Using multiple database connection string in web application web confing and changing the connection string base on the user in app_code file

I am working on a asp.net c# web appliaction where we have multiple connection strings defined in web config with differnet names and differnet databases, where the database name is selected based on the user at login, I have defined a public static sting 'db_name' in app code file (cs) and a public connection string in the same app code and passed the 'db_name' in the name proprty of connection string.

I am facing a issue where when mltiple users login at the same time ,all the data is stored in the database of the latest user logined.

I wanted to know wether the app code file complies evry time a new user login and that complied file  is used for other user

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, you really can't do this at all. You can't change "config", since all users work from that system. You can certainly define multiple databases in the connection string areas, but you certainly can't "change" the existing ones. VERY rare that each user would have their own database. I mean, what happens when you have 50 users, and now have to change the database structure? How you doing to manage that? I mean, to add a new customer, we don't create a WHOLE new database, but in fact add one customer to the table called customers. So, this idea of multiple databases? No, not workable.

Comment: You would have a place like db where there is connectionstring for each user.  Then when the user logs in you would simply get there their connection string from the db based on their id and use that connection string to talk to their database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can achieve this in a production envorment.

App_code will likely be re-compiled if you have a conneciton string class inside of app_code.

In fact, I don't use app_code anymore, since IIS will attempt to re-compile that code EVEN WHEN using a web site application that deploys compiled code.

So, I create a folder called MyCode, and place my class(s) and code inside of that.

But, your case gets MUCH worse. Since if you modify web.config, then IIS will detect this, and not only (often) trigger a re-compile of app_code, but will also do a WHOLE app_pool re-start, and that will blow out all users current session.

This idea of having each user their own database?

Nope, not even close to practial.

What happen after 50 users a and 50 databases, and you NOW want to change a database. Maybe a simple addition of a new view, or stored procedure. What now, you going to modify 50 databases?

You REALLY can't design ANY software, let alone web based software to work this way. I suppose on a desktop, ONE user can open ONE excel file, then close, and then open another.

However, in datbase land, and "espeically" web based?

You already dealing with a so called "state-less" system, and attempts to use mutliple different datbases created for each user?
Nope, not even close to ANY kind of practial design, and it NOT done, and thus even worse, the tools, the software, the system, the design approach?

ALL of your designs will have built around the assumption of a ONE database, and attempts to shoe-horn in some design that out of the blue is going to change the connection strings for one user?

You can't really do this. Each user does not have their "own" copy of the web server. You have ONE web server, and ANY user can post back a single page, and the web server's job is to process that ONE page. That use then might close their laptop, or start browsing amazon to shop. The web server has no clue that user does not exist anymore.

All you have, and ALL your designs must then assume the web server can and will process a incomming page from any and all users.

Boatloads, but beyond boatloads of designs and assumptions will have to work on this concept, and that includes things like user sessions, session management, code management (static class values are actually SHARED among all connected usres!!! - (which is why you can use static class(s) but you can NOT use static classes with variables scoped to that class!!!

As noted, you can and its often for a web site to use and connect to several databases, but NOT on per user bases - it will not work.

You can do this on a desktop, since EACH user has their own computer, own memory, and own software running on each desktop.

on a web server?

You have one computer, one system, and it has to serve "all" users, and things like connections etc. as a general rule are NOT to be "per user", but per "system".

A correctly normalized and correct database design will MORE then take care of each user needs like creating a new project, new tours or whatever.

Comment: The web application we are building is for different colleges with already existing databases and we want to give them a single software so we don't have to work 8 time on the same project

Comment: Do you have 6 separate sites, and thus 6 different instances of IIS sites running, or do they all use the one web site? This is a MASSIVE detail of your question, don't you think? If 6 different sites are being used, but you want one code base? Then on deployment you have to simply change the web config for each site deployed. If you have one URL for everyone, then no, you can't modify web config at all and that will not work. Best to have 6 web configs to be used at deployment time. If all are hitting the SAME URL site, then no, you can't change the connection settings in web.config

Comment: You could also have 6 database(s) and their connections in web config, and then have a setting for which database to use, however, this would work for the databases, but not the database that provides the users and their authentication - that will have to remain "one" database for the logon's. this really comes down to if we talking about one IIS instance and one URL to be used by everyone, or if this is going to be 6 different URL's and sites. If 6 different sites (instances), then again no problem, since the web config thus can be different for each site